# Where packets are stored on tshark using live capture?

Tags: save, wireshark, packet-capture, tshark, sniffer

I'm writing a real time sniffer using python and tshark and I'm a bit worried about where packets or data are stored in tshark. The idea is being able to execute the python script for days or weeks without stopping it and I'm not really sure if this concern could be a problem.

I have studied and have tried to understand tshark source code from [here](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/master/tshark.c) but I didn't found any line of code concerning this issue.

Is there anyone who knows how this works?

Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your issue. tshark will store packets where you tell it to. If you pipe the output to a Python script, they it all depends on where you store the output of the Python script.

Comment: Ok so, if I understand you, if I just print packets on stdout, then tshark will not create any temporary files to save data about packets?

Comment: It shouldn't need to. It stores packets in memory.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I'll make a proper answer with links to the source code when I get some time.

Comment: If you can, I'll appreciate it, but if you don't have time don't worry about it. Thank you @pchaigno

Answer (score 0):

So, by query, the packets captured on the interfaces are applied with the "filter" of the TShark options, and then redirected to the `stdout`. However, there exists provision to redirect it to `specific log file`, in `specified format`.

For Example:

```
tshark -T json  -i eth0 -O UDP -n > log.out
```

For more options, refer [here](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/tshark.html).